# Substitute Date issue/ and unterminated error

Tags: bash, sed

I am in need of some help and maybe some knowledge. 
I am trying to change all the dates in a .text document from dd/mm/yyy to dd.mm.yyy . I am not going to lie using sed confuses me so much! Can any of you help me?

```
`#  DAY          SEP    #2Month     SEP     #3year   min2,max4
sed 's/\[0-3]?[0-9\][.\/]\([0-1]*[0-9]\)[-\/.]\([0-9]\{2,4\}\)/\2.\1\3/'`
```

Here is my error sed: file Frank_Alvarado_hw2.sed line 5: unterminated `s' command.

```
Presidency ,President ,Wikipedia Entry,Took office ,Left office ,Party         ,Portrait ,Thumbnail,Home State                                                        
1,George  Washington,http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington,30/04/1789,4/03/1797,Independent ,GeorgeWashington.jpg,thmb_GeorgeWashington.jpg,Virginia
```

Comment: Post some sample input and expected output.

Comment: @EdMorton I put a sample up. Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

If those escapes are confusing in `sed` then use:

```
sed -r 's~([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{3})~\1.\2.\3~g' file
```

i.e.

1. Use of `-r` option for extended regex
2. Use of alternate regex delimiters like `~` to avoid escaping `/` in your pattern

**PS:** On OSX use `sed -E` instead of `sed -r`

Comment: sed -r 's~([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{3})~\1.\2.\3~g' presidents.csv
                                          new error                                                                                sed: file Frank_Alvarado_hw2.sed line 9: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Thank you for the info anubhava, it really cleans things up with the ~.

Comment: It says       GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: Could my problem possibly be with the way I put the file name?

Comment: yes that is the text file.. But I am still getting the : unknown option to `s' Error. I don't know what I am doing wrong

Comment: I am sorry anubhava, you just confused me. I have only been working with bash for 3 weeks.

Comment: I just wanted to check output of these commands in your shell to see where the problem is.

Comment: This was the output:   sed: file Frank_Alvarado_hw2.sed line 7: unterminated `s' command

Comment: I gave you 2 commands. Is the output of `type sed` that **unterminated** error?

Comment: Yes they were both the same : sed -r 's~([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{3})~\1.\2.\3~g' presidents.csv
and                                         :type  sed -r 's~([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{2})/([0-9]{3})~\1.\2.\3~g' presidents.csv

Comment: I think I have wasted huge time on this. You need to be able to at least follow instructions if nothing else. I wanted you to run just this command `type sed` and you are giving me some vague answers everytime

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 's/\[0-3]?[0-9\][.\/]\([0-1]*[0-9]\)[-\/.]\([0-9]\{2,4\}\)/\2.\1\3/'
       ^     ^^         ^ ^           ^       ^             ^       ^
       |     ||         | |           |       |             |       L 3th group (missing)
       |     ||         | |           |       |             L end of group 2
       |     ||         | |           |       L start of group 2
       |     ||         | |           L stop group 1
       |     ||         | L Start group 1
       |     ||         L class close so any `0123456789\\][./`
       |     |L class open
       |     L 0 or 1 occurence (of `]`)
       L escape the `[` (not a class open) so litteral char
```

so mainly, missing the third group reference in second pattern